# ARG puzzle, please help me with this

Tags: riddle, wordplay

I know, this is going to look, and sound very confusing, but I'm participating in an ARG.

The ARG, includes very difficult puzzles, and riddles that I cannot solve.

I need your help, I will provide as much details of the arg as possible.

Heres a picture of a puzzle that includes a code within it. You have to utilize the compass rose, to figure this one out.
[image: Compass Rose]

The creator of the ARG is named OPAL. Idk if that helps but it may.

Also heres a phrase that has something to do with the code or answer...
"Four Winds Become One When They Are The Farthest."

The code does not include any spaces, from my knowledge.

If you have any idea of what the code could be, either reply here, or try it out on this website. "https://arg.crescent.gg/chapter3/whereami.php"

if the code works, please reply with the answer!

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! Unfortunately, questions from ongoing contests are not allowed here - additionally, this does not seem to be a question that is self-contained, but an advertisement for something happening elsewhere (which is also disallowed on this site).

Comment: This question will remain locked until the event has been finished - once that happens, please flag this post so one of the moderators can unlock it.